# how to add hidden div or button behind the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

[image]can you please tell me how to add hidden div or  button behind the button?Actully I need to increase the click area without increase the x image size so that user can click in whole area.?

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="wrapper">
  <button id="openPopup">openPOP</button>
    <div data-role="popup" data-dismissible='false' id="testCaseId" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="a"><a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right cross-border">Close</a>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="testCaseIDValue">TestCase Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="testCaseIDValue" id="testCaseIDValue" value="" class="inputTextTestCase" />
        </div>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="donePopUp" class="common-button">Done</a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

js Code

```
$(function(){
  $('#openPopup').click(function(){




$( "#testCaseId" ).popup( "open" );
  })
})
```

[image]

Comment: didnt understand the question. Could you please explain?

Comment: Which button did you mean? There are more than "buttons" in your code.

Comment: As I show In image I want a div or button below the cross button.Actually I want to increase the cross button area .If user click outside It also close the pop up

Comment: this button <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right cross-border">Close</a>

Comment: when User click cross button it close teh pop up .I need to to increase the area .Actually it is small image .I need same small image but large area so I think I need to add invisible div

Comment: any update of this Qyestion

Answer (score 0):

Use the close icon as a centered background image of a larger element.

HTML

```
 <a href="#"></a>
```

CSS

```
a {
    display: block;
    background: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/mini/24/Close-icon.png") no-repeat center center #eee;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eAxb8/

Comment: I don't need like this ..Please apply this on my fiddle with alert

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems like you look for an invisible area that acts like a button.
See the following fiddle. To remove the blue color, just delete the code `style="background-color:lightblue"`

http://jsfiddle.net/p943a/2/

Comment: I think you don't understand the Question

Comment: Second solution is to set data-dismissible="true" but I guess you need it to be false :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a `<div>` that acts as a container for the button graphic and is the same color as your background, but clickable.

For example,

```
<a href = "whatever.com">
    <div id="hidden_button">
    <div id="button_graphic">
    Button Text
    </div>
    </div>
</a>

stylesheet.css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#hidden_button {
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    }

#button_graphic {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 4px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F38630;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 75px;
    }
```

If I've done my CSS correctly, this should create a square button with rounded edges that is 150px by 150px, with a container around it that is 300px by 300px and appears invisible, but is still clickable. Adjust the sizes to meet your needs.

Comment: Can you please share fiddle

Comment: Didn't use one. You can copy and paste this code into your own fiddle.

Comment: Actually here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p943a/ ..I need to increase the area of cross button.Please check my update Question